# Microsoft.Configuration.Extensions: How to get section / complex value as json string?

Tags: c#, .net-core, configuration-files

When we have configuration like this

```
// appsettings.json
{
    "SomeServiceConfiguration": {
       "Server": "127.0.0.1",
       "Port": "25"
    }
}
```

it is possible to use binding to access data:

```
IConfiguration configuration =  ...;
var section = configuration.GetSection("SomeServiceConfiguration");
var val = section.Value; // this is null
var t = new SomeServiceConfiguration();
section.Bind(t);
```

But is it possible to get value (section content)   **"just as string"** (by the fact as json) `{"Server": "127.0.0.1", "Port": "25"}` ?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking.  Are you asking how do you read a particular section of the `appsettings.json` into a string?

Comment: Yes. In case when it is complex type, not just plain string value. Help me to improove the question.

Comment: Because I want to deserialize it by myself

Comment: But you are already binding the object from the section, which should populate the object from the section values.

Comment: @RomanPokrovskij What do you mean by complex type?  You can deserialize into an object which contains strings, integers, other custom objects, etc.  Maybe share an example of the object you ultimately want to deserialize into?

Comment: I do not know internal representation of section. If it is a wrapper around of json fragment - I would like to get this fragment.

Comment: My sample is good enough. There is section named SomeServiceConfiguration, I can get it as 1) Section 2) Deserialized Type (through Bind method), But I would like to get it as string "{\"Server\": \"127.0.0.1\", \"Port\": \"25\"}".

Comment: If you want it as a string just store the text in a file and read it.  `IConfigurationProvider` isn't of much help to you here.

Comment: @JustinHelgerson IConfigurationProvider  is not used only for deserialization/binding.

Answer (score 1):

According to [`ConfigurationSection Class`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationsection?view=netframework-4.7.2#methods) this is not directly possible.

However, you could serialize to XML using the [`ConfigurationElement.SerializeElement(XmlWriter, Boolean)` Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationelement.serializeelement?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Configuration_ConfigurationElement_SerializeElement_System_Xml_XmlWriter_System_Boolean_), which is possible by default. You would have to convert to JSON afterwards, so this seems overkill.

I would recommend building a new `JSON Object` and accessing the section values directly.

Comment: Thank you. I also think that this impossible, abstraction of section "completely hides" internal data representation. Still I will left the question open, since I do not understand was this"completeness" necessay by design and could be it changed in future?