# How to read complex object from configuration file using microsoft.extensions.configuration

Tags: microsoft.extensions.configuration

I have following configuration file

```json
{
  "MyNamespace.Plugin": {
    "Setting": {
      "Path": "test"
    }
  }
}
```

And wrote following code to read it

```cs
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddJsonFile("settings.json")
                .Build();

var configuration = config.GetSection("MyNamespace.Plugin");

Setting setting = configuration.GetValue<Setting>("Setting");
```

However, I always get null for `setting`. Not sure where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to do following

```
var configuration = settings.Configuration.GetSection("MyNamespace.Plugin");

var settingSection = configuration.GetSection("Setting");
var setting = new Setting();
settingSection.Bind(setting);
```

Credit to the question raised at [Microsoft.Configuration.Extensions: How to get section / complex value as json string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52012599/1139856)

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you :)